# How to pass the model to a Controller in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, relationship

Say I have a Core Data class called RecipeBook which has a property (relationship) called recipes, a NSSet of Recipe Objects.

I display the RecipeBooks on a UITableView and when the user taps on a cell, it should display the Recipes on another UITableViewController.

What should I pass as the model to this last UITableViewController:

- a context and a fetchRequest
- or the NSSet of Recipe objects?

If there's a change to the db will the NSSet "automagically" update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description I'd probably pass the selected `RecipeBook` instance. From that I can (presumably) get all the recipes contained in the book and display them in the table. That assumes that a relationship exists from `RecipeBook` to `Recipe` which-- based on your description-- should be true. If I need to do any other work with the data store, I could ask the `RecipeBook` for its managed object context and work with that.

No `NSSet` of fetched objects is going to update automatically. But the relationship from a `RecipeBook` to its `Recipe`s will update any time a recipe is added or removed from the recipe book.

And finally-- passing any of this directly to a `UITableView` doesn't make a lot of sense. Apple's iOS frameworks are designed with MVC in mind, and going against that will make things a lot harder than they need to be. If you have a `UITableViewController`, you could pass your model objects to that.

Comment: Sorry, I meant UITableViewController, you're absolutely right. I already fixed the question.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you shouldn't pass "model" objects to view objects.
My favorite way to think about it is that views are actually another form of a model (think of them both as simply representations of data). The controller's job is to ensure that neither representation needs to know anything about how the other stores it's representation.

So basically, your controller will be your data delegate, and is responsible for properly populating table cells with it's own references to your core data models.

The automagically question depends on your core data setup, but usually the answer is yes.
By default, CD uses key-value coding, which simply lets you access properties with `valueForKey:`. More advanced setups involve having Xcode generate classes for you, in which case a few mouse clicks get you "dot notation" accessor methods regenerated from an updated model.